# Delphi plugin framework

Tags: delphi, com, dll, interface, bpl

I want to design Delphi plugin framework. There are three options:
1. DLL
2. BPL
3. COM interface
Every option has some disadvantage.

DLL - Promblem with MDI apllication, forms from plugin cannot be embeded to the host exe - mdi application.
BPL - Every *.bpl plugin and *.exe host application must be compiled with the same version of Delphi.
COM - Interfaces {xxx-xx-xxx-xx} must be registered in system, (regsvr) So plugin framework cannot be portable!

Is everything true what I wrote above? If not, please correct me, or is there some other possibility?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plugins system for Delphi application - bpl vs dll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192734/plugins-system-for-delphi-application-bpl-vs-dll)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of: [How best to add Plugin Capability to a Delphi program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365968/how-best-to-add-plugin-capability-to-a-delphi-program)

Comment: It's not the case that COM interfaces need to be registered. If you know where the implementing DLL is, you can load it and call its COM-related functions directly. There's no need to have the OS do it for you. And that makes it portable in *both* sense of the word: You can compile the code on other operating systems, and you can put the program on a USB drive and run it wherever you go.

Comment: I have read only a few articles about COM interfaces. From them I though, all COM interface must be regisetred in the system. I need portable application and therefore I rejected COM programming. But it seems, it is possible to make it portable. Thanks.  I must study COM techniques deeper ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, what you wrote is correct. All of these have advantages and disadvantages, the question is what is important for you, you didn't say what you want to do, so we can't tell you how to do it.

In general, I would pick BPL by default, use DLL if you need to use it from non Delphi apps, and pick COM only if you really have to.

The alternative is to not build your own, since there are several Delphi plugin frameworks available.

Also, this topic has been discussed here before, check out:

- [how-best-to-add-plugin-capability-to-a-delphi-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365968/how-best-to-add-plugin-capability-to-a-delphi-program)
- [plugins-system-for-delphi-application-bpl-vs-dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192734/plugins-system-for-delphi-application-bpl-vs-dll)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is having a scripting interface, such as with [Python](http://code.google.com/p/python4delphi/) or [Pascalscript](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx).  There are many advantages to this approach, not least of which is that the plugin source is also the executable, making it easy to debug and share.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx) from Remobjects.

Another candidate would be a combination of [PaxCompiler](http://www.paxcompiler.com/) (scripting) and [EControl Form Designer](http://www.econtrol.ru/formdsn.html) (form designer).

Answer (score 0):

We use DLLs, even when using only with a Delphi application.
Dll forms are embedded in the main form and use Tabs instead of MDI.
For DLL to work properly we also use a shared memory manager and built with runtime packages: vcl, rtl and our own package.

Comment: Yes, there are some workarounds how to baypass the error "cannot assign TFont to TFont" and TFrame from *.dll can be placed into host *.exe application, but there are some other problems with tab ordering with embeded TFrame, (after pressing tab key, focus is not moved to the next control in frame...) Or is there some workaround for it too?

Comment: Also arrow keys are not intercept by the form which means that TEdit and TMemo controls don't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tpf.asp